# Como pegar a versão de publicação de um console application

Tags: c#

Estou tendo um problema ao tentar pegar a versão de publicação da minha aplicação, pesquisei e encontrei a seguinte resposta no SOEN [how to show publish version in a textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690378/how-to-show-publish-version-in-a-textbox)

Segui exatamente o conceito da resposta certa porem uma exceção é lançada ao tentar pegar a versão da aplicação.

```
Version CurrentVersion = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion;    
String version = CurrentVersion.Major.ToString() + "." + CurrentVersion.Minor.ToString() + "." + CurrentVersion.Build.ToString() + "." + CurrentVersion.Revision.ToString();
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Afim de evitar que essa exceção seja lançada, você pode manipular a propriedade [`IsNetworkDeployed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.isnetworkdeployed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) do tipo booleano, retorna verdadeiro se o aplicativo é um aplicativo [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/142dbbz4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), falso se não.

```
using System.Deployment.Application;

if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
{
   Version CurrentVersion = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion;
   String version = CurrentVersion.Major.ToString() + "." + CurrentVersion.Minor.ToString() + "." + CurrentVersion.Build.ToString() + "." + CurrentVersion.Revision.ToString();
   // Faz alguma coisa aqui
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("Erro ao obter a versão de publicação");
}
```

A propriedade [`CurrentDeployment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.currentdeployment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) é válida somente dentro de um aplicativo em que o [`ClickOnce`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/142dbbz4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) esteja implantado, como explicado na *descrição*. No fórum do [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e01c2163-41a0-4bc0-80b8-79ae79db2bbb/how-to-get-the-publish-version-majorminorbuiltrevision?forum=csharpgeneral) encontrei um *snippet* que pode fazer esse trabalho independente se for um aplicativo ClickOnce ou não.

```
System.Version version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", version.Major, version.Minor, version.Revision, version.Build));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: o segundo exemplo a versão sempre vem 1.0.0.0 mesmo que a versão do Build esteja diferente :(